# Where I can use dispose? VB.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Can anyone help where I can put dispose method on this one? so that the variable I use won't be save in the memory. I'm having where should I put or when should I use it.

I tried doing

> myQuery.Dispose()

but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    mysqlConn.Open()
    If TextBox01.Text = "" Or TextBox02.Text = "" Or TextBox04.Text = "" Or TextBox05.Text = "" Or TextBox06.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in all boxes")
        Exit Sub

    Else

        sqlCmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand
        sqlCmd.Connection = mysqlConn
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_user where username='" & TextBox05.Text & "' Or email='" & TextBox04.Text & "' "
        dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Username or Email already Exist", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else

            Dim myQuery As String

            myQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('" & Replace(Trim(TextBox01.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(TextBox02.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(TextBox04.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(TextBox05.Text), "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Trim(TextBox06.Text), "'", "''") & "')"


            sqlCmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand
            sqlCmd.Connection = mysqlConn
            sqlCmd.CommandText = myQuery

            dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("You are now register!", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Me.Hide()
            frmMenu.Hide()
            frmLogin.Show()

            TextBox01.Text = ""
            TextBox02.Text = ""
            TextBox04.Text = ""
            TextBox05.Text = ""
            TextBox06.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
    mysqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you try to dispose a string?

Comment: I'm trying to dispose the thing that I input in all of the textbox. That's why I'm trying to ask if there is something that I need to change or do to use the dispose

Comment: `Dispose()` is generally for cleaning up objects which contain unmanaged (i.e. outside of .NET/CLR) resources. `String` doesn't implement `Dispose()` because it's entirely managed memory; no unmanaged cleanup needed. If you have sensitive information you don't want to hang around in memory - check out [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: PS, do yourself a favor and look up SQL parameterization. Your SQL query is open to SQL injection attacks. Concatenating values into a query, instead of using parameters, is _bad_.

Comment: MySQL has its own provider. It will be much better to use than ODBC. Don't open your connection until right before you use it. The objects you need to dispose are your connection, and possibly the reader and Command. A Using block will figure it out for you, closing and disposing of objects when necessary. In a real application, passwords would never be stored as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Objects implement the [IDisposable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) by default, and will be automatically disposed of when [Object.Finalize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx) is run by garbage collection.

In your question you are trying to dispose a string which is "technically" an object, but is an object that acts as a variable, and cannot be disposed of.

You could dispose of mysqlConn after mysqlConn.close() if you wanted to free up memory before garbage collection happened. sqlCmd could also be disposed of. In general though, I would not use the Dispose() method unless you have a specific issue (mainly memory constraint) that you are trying to address. The .NET runtime does a great job of managing this for you.